# Code not working after upgrade to PHP7

Tags: php, php-7

I have problem with my PHP code after upgrade PHP to version 7.

```
                <?php
                include ("dbconfig.php");
                    $conn->select_db("zapis");
                echo "<div class="form-group">";
                echo "<select class="form-control" id="sel1">";
                                $zapytanie = $conn->query("SELECT id, oferta FROM ofertameska");
                                while($row = $zapytanie->fetch_assoc()){
                                     echo "<option value=".{$row['id']}.">".{$row['oferta']}."</option>";
                                }
                echo "</select>";
        echo "</div>";
                $zapytanie->free();
                $conn->close();
      ?>
```

What's wrong?

Error message is:

> Error: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'mysqli' not found in /var/www/html/hest/meski/dbconfig.php:5

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: @Devon, When I remove PHP code from script all is ok ( I see forms from html), but when I add PHP code, then i see only white page. When I use phpinfo(), I can see information about PHP version.

Comment: Enable error reporting

Comment: @Devon Error: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'mysqli' not found in /var/www/html/hest/meski/dbconfig.php:5 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/hest/meski/index.php(51): include() #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/hest/meski/dbconfig.php on line 5   For connect with mysql database i use: $conn = new mysqli($server, $username, $password);

Comment: You haven't enabled `mysqli` in your PHP configuration.

Comment: Ok, I solved it by install php7.0-mysqli. Thx guys! :)

Comment: Upgrading to PHP7 might kill off a few of your modules, while you are in module land, may i suggest checking out the PDO Database options?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you just need to [install MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.installation.php).

If you think you've done that and still have a problem, please post your operating system and anything else that might help.

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable the mysqli-extension in the new php.ini?